# Everything in focus with d750

Tags: focus, nikon-d750

as you can see the flowers are not focused, I cannot focus everything, I have to chose the squirrel or the flowers, is it normal? 
THANK you

D750
28-300

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes.

The key things that determine depth-of-field are aperture and distance to the focus point. The closer the item, the less depth-of-field (less will be in focus). The wider the aperture (lower the aperture value), the less depth-of-field. Distance to focus point has a much greater impact than aperture.

So you could try going for a smaller aperture (e.g. f13 or f22) and focusing in front of the squirrel. But depending on how close those flowers are, that may not work. It's a physical limitation of lenses.

For some scenes you will learn that you cannot get everything in focus. In those situations, you can do "focus stacking" in Photoshop (and other image editors). Take two shots, one focused on the flowers and one focused on the squirrel. It helps to do this with a tripod. Then use the focus stacking software to build a single image where everything is in focus from the two images.

Comment: You will probably have some difficulty getting the squirrels to remain still for the ten or so shots required for focus stacking!

Comment: Great humour, has a terrible aftertaste of "some psycho bastard might actually try" though...

Comment: And... mind the influence of focal length ... the OP is using a superzoom, and very different practical advice could apply at 28 vs 300mm....